# Java Calendar shows wrong amount of weeks when first week of month is defined as week in which 1 occurs

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I've made a function that should get the number of weeks for a given month. For January, May, July and October, it should return 5 weeks. 
However, it returns 5 for March, June, September. and November. Surprisingly, the total amount of weeks are correct (52).

```
public static int getNofWeeksWithFirstWeekStartingWhenFirstDayOfMonthOccurs(Calendar calendar) {

    while (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {
        calendar.roll(Calendar.DATE, true);
    }
    int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int nextMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;
    int prePreviousMonth = (currentMonth + 12 - 2) % 12;
    int nofWeeks = 0;
    do {
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        if (month == nextMonth) {
            nofWeeks++;
        }
        if (month == prePreviousMonth) {
            break;
        }
        calendar.roll(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, true);
    } while (true);
    return nofWeeks;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numWeeks;
    int totalWeeks=0;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY);
    numWeeks=getNofWeeksWithFirstWeekStartingWhenFirstDayOfMonthOccurs(calendar);
    System.out.println("no of weeks " + numWeeks);
}
```

**Output: 
no of weeks 4**

Month start is in Week that has first day. e.g.:

25 - 1 May
2 - 8 May
9 - 15 May
16 - 22 May
23 - 29 May

5 Weeks in May:

[image]

Comment: How many weeks do you think March has? It's kinda hard to stuff 31 days into four weeks.

Comment: Also note that you've shown *6* weeks in May... weeks 17 to 22 inclusive.

Comment: What your code gets is "weeks that start in month x", so 5 is correct.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 1st of march 2016 is: 29 febr. - 6 march, 2nd: 7 - 13 march, 3th: 14 - 20 march, last week: 21 - 27 march.

Comment: @JonSkeet The week that has the 1st day is the first week of the new month. The last week of may is: 23 - 29 may.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper if that is true, how come April returns 4?

Comment: Basically, it's unclear what your `getNoOfWeeks` is meant to return. It sounds like you probably have a very specific idea of what you expect it to do, but you haven't included that in the post. Once you do so, it'll be a lot easier to help you. (Aside from anything else, "The week that has the 1st day is the first week of the new month" is only one possible definition of weeks, and not the normal ISO one.)

Comment: It would have been clearer to just describe the desired functionality in the question, very specifically. (Also, do you want the "start of week" to be culture-sensitive, or always Monday?)

Comment: @JonSkeet start of week date is always monday

Comment: Okay. *All* of this should be in the question, in words, very clearly.

Comment: I've added an answer describing the rough algorithm, but to turn it into code... do you *have* to use `java.util.Calendar`, or could you use the somewhat-saner APIs of Joda Time or java.time.*?

Comment: @JonSkeet it just has to work. start of week Monday is not relevant I think.

Comment: It's *completely* relevant... it determines how many days are effectively "borrowed" from the previous month. For example, imagine your May calendar as shown, but with Sunday as the first week of the month - then there would only be 4 weeks instead of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you should:

- Work out the first day of the month
- Determine from that how many "extra" days are "borrowed" from the previous month (e.g. 0 if day 1 is a Monday; 1 if day 1 is a Tuesday etc)
- Add that to the number of days in the regular month
- Divide by 7 (with implicit truncation towards 0)

There's no need to do half the work you're currently doing.

Using `java.util.Calendar`, it would be something like:

```
// Note: day-of-week runs from Sunday (1) to Saturday (7).
// Entry 0 here is not used. We could do this without an array lookup
// if desired, but it's whatever code you think is clearest.
private static final int[] EXTRA_DAYS = { 0, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

// Note: 0-based month as per the rest of java.util.Calendar
public static int getWeekCount(int year, int month) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
    int dayOfWeekOfStartOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int extraDays = EXTRA_DAYS[dayOfWeekOfStartOfMonth];
    int regularDaysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int effectiveDaysInMonth = regularDaysInMonth + extraDays;
    return effectiveDaysInMonth / 7;
}
```

If at all possible, I'd recommend using Joda Time or `java.time` instead, however.

With that code, the results for 2016 are:

- January: 5
- February: 4
- March: 4
- April: 4
- May: 5
- June: 4
- July: 5
- August: 4
- September: 4
- October: 5
- November: 4
- December: 4

Answer (score -1):

From the comments I deduce that you want to count the number of weeks in a month starting at the 1st of the month.

You need to:

- Set the day of the month to `1`
- add forward, not roll backward
- start on Sunday instead of Monday

The code would be something like this:

```
public static int getNofWeeksWithFirstWeekStartingWhenFirstDayOfMonthOccurs(Calendar calendar) {
    while (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        calendar.roll(Calendar.DATE, true);
    }
    int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int nextMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;
    int prePreviousMonth = (currentMonth + 12 - 2) % 12;
    int nofWeeks = 0;
    do {
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        if (month == currentMonth) {
            nofWeeks++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
        calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
    } while (true);
    return nofWeeks;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numWeeks;
    int totalWeeks=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, i);
    numWeeks=getNofWeeksWithFirstWeekStartingWhenFirstDayOfMonthOccurs(calendar);
    System.out.println("no of weeks " + numWeeks);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
no of weeks 5
no of weeks 4
no of weeks 4
no of weeks 4
no of weeks 5
no of weeks 4
no of weeks 5
no of weeks 4
no of weeks 4
no of weeks 5
no of weeks 4
no of weeks 4
```

Comment: Added: calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
Changing false to true: calendar.roll(Calendar.DATE, true); makes it not work at all anymore.

Comment: Do you still use previousMonth or have you changed that to nextMonth?

Comment: Can you post a code example? I should change "previousMonth" to "nextMonth"? A textual change?

Comment: Not just the name but also the assignment: `int nextMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;`

Comment: Edited the question with your improvements. January & July is now correct, 5 weeks. But the rest is still not OK.

Comment: Code gives back wrong week numbers: 

4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,4,4

Correct:

5,
4,
4,
4,
5,
4,
5,
4,
4,
5,
4,
4

Comment: Seems rolling is weird at year breaks if there are 53 weeks in a year, so I switched to `add` instead of `roll`. Also, I changed the first roll to stay at Sunday instead of Monday. No it looks like it works.